# option selected with val() function

Tags: jquery

I have the following html

```
<select id="message_type" name="message_type" class="inputbox" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="option1">Suggestion</option>
    <option value="option2">Inquiry</option>
    <option value="option3">Offers</option>
</select>
```

And the jquery is

```
$('#message_type').val( option2 );
```

But this is not selected option2 that is Inquiry. How can I make sure the option2 is selected? What's wrong here?

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PnuPJ/)

Comment: The code is taking `option2` as a variable/object which is undefined, you need to pass it as a string `'option2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
$('#message_type').val("option2");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PnuPJ/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LSQZT/)**

option2 should be string, not object or variable

```
  $('#message_type').val( "option2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing right for making option2 selected. It should be a parameter value which is a type of `string`.

Try this

```
$('#message_type').val('option2');
```

OR

```
$('#message_type option[value="option2"]').attr('selected', true);
```

OR

```
$('#message_type option[value="option2"]').prop('selected', true);
```

Here is the working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PnuPJ/2/)

Comment: thanks for different code..... but actually I have this type of code $('#message_type').val( optIndx !=-1 ? hash : '' ); and it's not working that is because it is an object which has not " "?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the option's value as a parametr. Try this

```
$('#message_type').val('option2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this **$('#message_type').val( 'option2' );** Its working fine for me.